# Removing effect of a CSS selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My requirement is a bit tricky. I have a mark-up as below: (just an example, real mark-up is very complicated)

```
    <div class="classA">
        <div class="classB">
            <p class="classC">
                <span class="classD">
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see above, there are four CSS classes `classA, classB, classC, classD` associated with the markup.
Also I have used jQuery to bind events using these selectors.

**My Requirement**: I want the jQuery event binding to work and at the same time, the CSS should not get applied i.e. I want to negate the impact of CSS styles from a UI perspective, but from functional perspective jQuery event handlers should still work.

So, is it possible to override the CSS selectors such that their styles don't get applied to my mark-up elements ?

example below:

```
div.classA div.classB p.classC span.classD{
    color:red;
}
```

I don't want the font color to be red, so I tried to override the selector as follows, but its not working:

```
div.classA div.classB p.classC span.classD{
    color:red;
}

div.classA div.classB p.classC span.classD{
   /*no styles here*/
}
```

Please help !!

Comment: Logically modify the css class names so that the style will not apply but they can still be selected by altering the name by the modification.

Comment: @TravisJ can you please elaborate, I did not understand

Comment: It is a requirement !!

Answer (score 0):

Then just delete those classes from css. jQuery will still work though.

There is no requirement that only classes used in css have to be used in jquery.

For example:

```
<div class="someUnknownClass"></div>
```

Even though, there is no someUnknownClass defined in css, `$('.someUnknownClass')` will still work.

Comment: I cannot delete those classes from css, because I want this only for one of the screens in my site. For other screens, the styles should get applied. And we use common css file accross all the screens.

Comment: Yes, but its lot of legacy code written and I was thinking if there was a way that I can achieve this requirement without touching the complex legacy code.
Basically, I do not want to touch the js code, and only if something can be done on the css front, then my requirement is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any mechanism allowing to do that the way you want it.
the work around i would suggest would be binding your events on anoter css class and doing something like this :

```
$('.classD').addClass('eventClassD').removeClass('classD');
$('.eventClassD').on('myEvent', function(){...});
```

like this you will still have events binded to your elements and would get rid of all the css.

Answer (score 0):

Use another class name for the selector. So you have `classA` for the css and `classX` for the selector.

If you don't want the styles applied. Then you could use `$('selctor').css();` to over write the styles. Bit hacky!
OR. 
Add a class that over-rides the css. Or remove the class that holds the css.
using: `$('selctor').addClass('no_styles');` OR `$('selctor').removeClass('current_styles');`

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it without modifying the JS? There's no clean way to do that. But try this.

Presumably you will have something that distinguishes this special set of elements to distinguish it from other elements, of which styles' you want to retain. This is difference probably manifests itself in the form of a different parent container. Just copy the set of CSS rules that affect these classes, and prepend this parent CSS selector with the pre-class values.

Answer (score 0):

"Basically, I do not want to touch the js code, and only if something can be done on the css front, then my requirement is achieved."

If that is all you need, then just remove all of the css definitions from the page.

```
$("link,style").remove()
```